# How to get first letter of all strings in an array in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I have a group of strings stored in an array.

```
stringArray = [Aruna, Bala, Chitra, Divya, Fatima]
```

I want to get the first letters of all the strings and store it in an array. 
Like: `letterArray = [A, B, C, D, F]`

Note: They are not within quotes "--"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'they are not within quotes', but if they are actually Strings then something like this:

```
var letterArray = [Character]()
for string in stringArray {
    letterArray.append(string.characters.first!)
}
```

**EDIT**

To have it as `String` instead as you wish:

```
var letterArray = [String]()
for string in stringArray {
    letterArray.append(String(string.characters.first!))
}
```

**EDIT 2**

As [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) suggests, if you pass an empty string the above will fail. If you know there will never be an empty string this doesn't apply, but I've updated the above to handle this case:

```
var letterArray = [String]()
for string in stringArray {
    if let letter = string.characters.first {
        letterArray.append(String(letter))
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: SWIFT 4**

From Swift 4 `characters` has been deprecated. Instead of using `string.characters.first` you should now operate on the String directly using just `string.first`. For example:

```
var letterArray = [String]()
for string in stringArray {
    if let letter = string.first {
        letterArray.append(String(letter))
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the `letterAray` as `[String]` instead of `[Character]` is it possible?

Comment: But they're not strings, they're just characters. What use case do you have where a character vs. a string with one letter in it matters so much?

Comment: Updated it to store as a String instead.

Comment: @AAA be aware that forcing unwrapping like this would crash your app in case you pass an array that has an empty string

Comment: Updated to handle this case since I prefer my own solutions readability.

Comment: Swift 4: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

Answer (score 14):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

```
extension Collection where Element: StringProtocol {
    var initials: [Element.SubSequence] {
        return map { $0.prefix(1) }
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 8 • Swift 3**

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    var initials: [String] {
        return map{String($0.characters.prefix(1))}
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 7.3.1 • Swift 2.2.1**

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == String {
    var initials: [String] {
        return map{ String($0.characters.prefix(1)) }
    }
}


let stringArray = ["Aruna", "Bala", "Chitra", "Divya", "Fatima"]

let initials = stringArray.initials  // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
```

Comment: Great answer, can we make the array of unique initials i.e. non-repetative in the extension?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj stackoverflow.com/a/39324354/2303865 just add .orderedSet to `stringArray.initials.orderedSet`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try my solution.

```
let stringArray = ["Aruna", "Bala", "Chitra", "Divya", "Fatima"]

let result = stringArray.map({ $0.prefix(1) }) // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
```