# String may not be indexed with 'Int' Swift3

Tags: swift, string

i'm trying to display the first letter of my contact name in uppercase:

```
 var firstLetter: String? = !(contact?.firstName == "") ? (contact?.firstName as? String)?.substring(to: 1).uppercased() : (contact?.lastName as? String)?.substring(to: 1).uppercased()
```

but i have got this error:

```
String may not be indexed with 'Int', it has variable size elements
```

Comment: `String` is indexed by `String.Index`, not `Int`, compare [How does String.Index work in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39676939/2976878). Although in your case, you can use `string.characters.first`, which will give you the first character of the string, or `nil` if the string is empty – compare [How to get first letter of all strings in an array in iOS Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33792991/2976878).

Comment: What type is contact here? Can you show the definition of "contact" type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if let contact = contact
    {
        var firstLetter = !contact.firstName.isEmpty ? contact?.firstName.characters.first?.description.uppercased() : contact?.lastName.characters.first?.description.uppercased()
    }
```

I will be able to help you more if you tell the type/definition of "contact".

Comment: voici la déclaration de contact:         var contact: TContact? = TContactsManager.shared().getContactByJID(self.bareJid!.full())

Comment: Definition of TContact?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to get first letter in capital format. Before the call check if your string is empty then don't call as you are doing in your code

```
func capitalizeFirst() -> String {
        let firstIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        return self.substring(to: firstIndex).capitalized + self.substring(from: firstIndex).lowercased()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find the first character, you can use `contact?.uppercased().characters.first`.
In general, to get the n-th character in uppercase, use `contact?.uppercased()[contact?.index(contact?.startIndex, offsetBy: n)]`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the long chain of indirections and make the function a bit clearer you could also write it like this :

```
firstLetter = ( (contact?.firstName ?? "") + (contact?.lastName ?? "") )
              .characters.first?.description.uppercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstLetter = (contact?.firstName.characters.first ?? contact?.lastName.characters.first)?.description.uppercased()
```